# kafka rest api - connection refused

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using kafka_2.11.-0.9.0.1.

First, I started the zookeeper & kafka (as explained [here](http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html)) with:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

and then:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Now I'm trying to GET some info from the REST API (as explained [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_rest)) with:

```
[itay@localhost general]$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8083/connectors
--2016-04-27 10:44:26--  http://127.0.0.1:8083/connectors
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8083... failed: Connection refused.
```

Kafka & zookeeper are up & running, My application is connected with them and sending/receiving messages.

what did I miss? any suggestions? (I didn't find instruction of firing up web-server/port.. )

Thanks

Comment: BTW why are you using Kafka 0.7 docs?

Comment: Where can I find the correct one?

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart

Comment: You need to start Kafka REST Proxy: http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html

Answer (score 3):

Running Kafka and Zookeeper are not enough to use this REST API, because, according to documentation "REST interface - submit and manage connectors to your Kafka Connect cluster via an easy to use REST API". So you need first run Kafka Connect framework in standalone or distributed mode, and then starts service for connectors (which realize streaming data beetween Kafka and other systems), which support this REST API. You also read Confluent documentation for Connect Kafka (http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/) to better understand this issue.
Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Yes, alone Zookeeper and Kafka doesn't work. Need to run Kafka connect too.

Run Kafka Connect in Distributed Mode :

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
```

and hit http://localhost:8083/connectors/

It worked for me.